How do I set up openslide in my Vs Code environment?
Source code: https://github.com/vqdang/hover_net?tab=readme-ov-file
I am struggling to set up the environment required to use this github repo:
name: hovernet
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.12
  - pip=20.3.1
  - openslide
  - pip:
    - -r file:requirements.txt
    - openslide-python==1.1.2

I keep getting this error code:

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

I am aware that openslide is optimized for linux, but all I have access to right now a windows laptop.
I downloaded python 3.6.12 and I created a kernel that runs on python 3.6.12.
To get openslide working on my computer, I used this: https://www.msys2.org/ to download openslide. After downloading it and unzipping the file I changed every the code under the 'examples' folder from the source code from import openslide to this:
OPENSLIDE_PATH = r'C:\Users\cheukjy\Downloads\openslide-bin-4.0.0.3-windows-x64\openslide-bin-4.0.0.3-windows-x64\bin'

import os
if hasattr(os, 'add_dll_directory'):
    # Windows
    with os.add_dll_directory(OPENSLIDE_PATH):
        import openslide
else:
    import openslide

I still get the error:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

I expected it to work use openslide under MSYS2 and run the code normally, but it didn't work.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if you have it on local disk then you may need pip install /full/path/to/module/on/disk but you run all time pip install openslide-python==1.1.2 so it searchs it on internet
